# Last Row in Range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Having an issue finding information and/or solutions that produce the desired result, so here it goes.

Right now, and potentially at production time, i will have a "template" named-range on a worksheet.  On first use this NamedRange is only `rngNamed1` but after the first use there could be more Named Ranges similar to this one, say up to `rngNamed30`.

Lets say on the 2nd run after building up to `rngNamed30`, that i need to add 3 more of the NamedRange, which results in `rngNamed33`.

What i need to do is basically find the last row & column of the last Named Range, so i know where to start the copying of data to and declare the next Named Range.

#### What i have tried so far:

```
Dim rng As range
Set rng = range("rngNamed1")
'Set rng = rng.Find("*", rng.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False)
Debug.Print rng.Find("*", rng.Cells(1, 1), , , , xlPrevious).Address
```

The problem with most of the solutions out there is they are based on finding the last cell WITH DATA.  I just need to know the Last Cell of the Range, irregardless of whether it contains data or not.

Comment: `Range("X").Row` returns the first row of the range named X.  `Range("X").Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in range X.  Put these together and you can calculate the last row of the range.  Range("X").Address returns an address string which can be decoded.  Would either of these techniques help?

Comment: Yeah kinda figured that....was trying to make sure that there wasnt some obscure option in SpecialCells or some other internal method that would provide the information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this easily using the Row and Rows.Count of the range:

```
Sub NextRowAfterRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rangeNom As String
    Dim nextRow As Long

    ' Enter desired name here
    rangeNom = "rngName1"

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    nextRow = ws.Range(rangeNom).Row + ws.Range(rangeNom).Rows.Count

    MsgBox nextRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Its good practise to use long when dimensioning rows, not integer.  The number of rows in excel 2007 onwards exceeds integer limits.  Another way:  `Debug.Print rng(rng.Rows.Count, 1)(2).Row`

Comment: yeah i learned that lesson back in VB6....even though i know its going to be about 1/100 the max value of Int, its always better to be data-type consistent and not hope the type casting (implicit) does it correctly ;)