# Set range to last row

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to set range to last row.

I have

```
For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:CG100").Cells 'adjust sheetname and range accordingly
```

I tried

```
For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:CG" & lastRow).Cells 'adjust sheetname and range accordingly
```

But not working

The problem is that the last row changes, if I use entire column the the Sub runs forever

```
Sub CleanAll()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:CG100").Cells 'adjust sheetname and range accordingly
        rng.Value = NumberOnly(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Iterating over every cell in a large range is almost always a bad idea and bad design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last Row in Range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588424/last-row-in-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code : You may also refer this [link](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/) for details.

```
Sub CleanAll()

        Dim rng As Range

        For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").CurrentRegion
            rng.Value = NumberOnly(rng.Value)
        Next
 End Sub
```

OR

```
 Sub CleanAll()

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim lastCol As Long
        Dim colChr As String


        With Sheets("sheet1")
            lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
        End With


        For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
           rng.Value = NumberOnly(rng.Value)
        Next
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub CleanAll()

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long

        With Sheets("sheet1")
            lastRow = .Range("CG" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:CG" & lastRow)
            rng.Value = NumberOnly(rng.Value)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: I advise against the first option. If you have sections (separations in the content) in your spreadsheet it will fail to calculate the correct range. I'd use the second one.

Comment: This is Great, does the 2nd option work if CG is not the last column? Thanks again Santosh

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth this question has been done to death but I use something different:

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells
    last_column = .Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    last_row = .Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
```